How to Visualise ELB Logs from S3 in Grafana?
I am trying to visualize S3 logs in Grafana, which are collected from a load balancer. The logs are available at:
test-bkp/AWSLogs/851725603941/elasticloadbalancing/us-east-2/year/month/date/*.gz


What is the best method to do this? Is there any tool I can use, or can it be done using Loki or InfluxDB? Please suggest, and if possible, guide me on how to set it up.
I tried using Loki, but I didn't get good results.
I have:
server1: Grafana, Loki, and Prometheus are installed.
server2: My application is running, handled by a load balancer, and the logs are collected in S3.
The logs path in S3:
test-bkp/AWSLogs/851725603941/elasticloadbalancing/us-east-2/year/month/date/*.gz

So, I tried the following steps:
Installed Promtail on server1 (where Loki is already installed).
My promtail-local-config.yaml:
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /data/loki/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://x.x.x.x:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "local-s3-logs"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost']
        labels:
          job: "s3-logs"
          __path__: /var/log/s3-logs/**/*.log.gz


Sync script:
My sync-s3-logs.sh:
#!/bin/bash
# Sync S3 logs to local directory

BUCKET="s3://test-bkp/AWSLogs/851725603941/elasticloadbalancing/us-east-2/"
LOCAL_DIR="/var/log/s3-logs/"

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p $LOCAL_DIR

# Sync the logs from S3 to the local directory
aws s3 sync $BUCKET $LOCAL_DIR


Running the sync script through systemd:
/etc/systemd/system/s3-sync.service:
[Unit]
Description=S3 Sync Service for ELB Logs
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/s3-sync/sync-s3-logs.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


/etc/systemd/system/s3-sync.timer:
[Unit]
Description=Run S3 Sync Service every 1 minute

[Timer]
OnBootSec=1min
OnUnitActiveSec=1min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target



What is the best method to do this? - that's opinionated question. How one should know what is the best for you? IMHO my best: S3 trigger for any new files, which will trigger Lambda. which will parse file from S3 and ingest it into your Loki.

Agree with Jan. Look at Lambda Promtail and Loki
